# How do I convert a Map in LIst to a Map?

Tags: scala

In detail, I want the key of Map to be the date and time, and the value to be Map(person's name -> the maximum value taken by that person on that date and time).
How can I do this?

```
val d = Map(2020-01-30 -> Seq(Map("fff" -> 177), Map("fsdzf" -> 219), Map("fff" -> 300), Map("fff" -> 0)), 2020-01-26 -> Seq(Map("fvcfdf" -> 188), Map("vav" -> 273)))
```

TI want the code above to look like the code below.

```
Map(2020-01-30 -> Map(fff -> 300, fsdzf -> 219), 2020-01-26 -> Map(fvcfdf -> 188, vav -> 273))
```

Comment: Hint: convert each inner map to sequence, flatten that sequence of sequences, group by the first element and transform the result to take the max value of the second element. There is several ways you can do it, but you should be able to figure that out yourself by using your IDEs intellisense to list available operations.

Comment: May I have one example?

Comment: use `groupMap` + `vew.mapValues` or `groupMapReduce`

Comment: Another style for scala 3.x `d.map(_ -> _.flatten.groupMapReduce(_._1)(_._2)(_ max _))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
   originalMap
    .view
    .mapValues(_.flatten)
    .mapValues(_.groupMapReduce(_._1)(_._2)(_ max _))
    .toMap
```

Basically, get rid of inner maps first (turn values of outer map into lists of tuples), then group those tuples by first element, and for each group select max of the second.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you would want the `"values"` (mapValues) of your outer `Map`, which is a list of some maps, to be aggregated into a single Map (folding):

```scala
d.mapValues { listOfInnerMaps => 
  listOfInnerMaps.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int])(_ ++ _)
}

// or a shorter version of the above thing:
d.mapValues(_.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int])(_ ++ _))
```

If you're sure that the Lists are always non-empty, you can also use reduce (which I would not recommend):

```scala
d.mapValues(listOfInnerMaps => listOfInnerMaps.reduce(_ ++ _))
// or a shorter version of the above thing:
d.mapValues(_.reduce(_ ++ _))
```

## Update

So if you want the max value of each inner map, I would suggest you to iterate over the list, and update an accumulator of `Map[String, Int]` only if the new value is bigger than the old value:

```scala
d.mapValues { listOfMaps => 
  listOfMaps.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]) {
    case (acc, newMap) => 
      newMap.foldLeft(acc) {
        case (updatingAcc, (key, value)) => 
          updatingAcc.updatedWith(key) {
            case Some(oldValue) if value > oldValue => Some(value)
            case None => Some(value)
            case other => other
          }
      }
  }
}.toMap
```

Comment: This code is MapView(<not computed>).

Comment: Just add a `toMap` at the end, and to avoid deprecation warnings call `.view` before the `mapValues`

Comment: This code result is Map(1989 -> Map(fff -> 0, fsdzf -> 219), 1993 -> Map(fvcfdf -> 188, vav -> 273)).

Comment: The results I want are Map(2020-01-30 -> Map(fff -> 300, fsdzf -> 219), 2020-01-26 -> Map(fvcfdf -> 188, vav -> 273)).

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't notice the "maximum value" you wanted, I'll just update the answer.